# Метод wall.get — квадратики вместо смайлов (VK API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

При использовании метода VK API `wall.get`, пытаясь получить предложенный пост со смайлами, получаю предложенный пост, но вместо смайлов — квадратики. Пробовал менять кодировку — ничего не получается.

Использую PHP и [класс VK](https://github.com/vladkens/VK). Пробовал отлавливать ответ сразу после cURL, но там тоже квадратики, так что класс тут не при чём.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Квадратики это шрифты, которых нет, и они не знают как себя отобразить. Видимо шрифтовую библиотеку нужно ещё брать

Comment: У них вместо смайлов юникодные символы, соответствующие смайлам. Похоже, просто символ шрифта под символы не нашелся

Comment: Если сразу после метода wall.get  применить метод wall.post с текстом полученным из wall.get. то смайлы в вк появляются, но мне бы хотелось менять смайлы местами или добавлять удалять. Этого не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // преобразуем юникод код смайла в символы типа &\#11111
    $tmp = $post['text'];
    $arr_tmp = utf8_to_unicode_code($tmp);
    $arr_smile = explode(';',$smile);                
    foreach($arr_smile as $key => $val) {
        $key_smile = array_keys($arr_tmp,$val);
        if(!empty($key_smile)) {                        
            //если несколько одинаковых смайлов
            $arr = $key_smile;
            if (!is_array($key_smile)){
                $arr = array($key_smile);
            }
            $cod_smile = utf8_to_unicode_code($arr_tmp[reset($key_smile)]);
            //удаляем начальный символ юникода
            unset($cod_smile[0]);
            foreach($arr as $v){
                $key_smile = array_search($val,$arr_tmp);
                $merg_arr = array_merge(array(38, 92, 35) , $cod_smile, array(59));                
                array_splice($arr_tmp, $key_smile , 1, $merg_arr);                
            }
        }
    }

function utf8_to_unicode_code($utf8_string) {
    $expanded = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-32", $utf8_string);
    //array_merg для того чтоб индексация начиналачь с 0
    return array_merge(unpack("L*", $expanded),array());
}

function unicode_code_to_utf8($unicode_list) {
    $result = "";
    foreach($unicode_list as $key => $value) {
        $one_character = pack("L", $value);
        $result .= iconv("UTF-32", "UTF-8", $one_character);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

вариант не идеальный но рабочий, вся соль в функциях